# Символы в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Добрый день, работая в связке с TextView + EditView (отображение текста (в 1), а точнее цифр, введенных в Edit (2)) приложение дописывает символ валюты, (если локация на устройстве RU - дописывает руб., если EN - дописывает $)

вопрос - как это убрать? чтобы приложение не дописывало ничего

пытался через  Html.fromHtml - однако итог руб.+мойтекст

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.delari.myapplication2.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:columnCount="2"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
   />

 </GridLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private TextView TextView;
private double Amount = 0.0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    EditText amountEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher);
}

private final TextWatcher EditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {
        try {
            Amount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) / 100.0;
            TextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(Amount));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            TextView.setText("");
            Amount = 0.0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
};
}
```

В самом классе активите ничего подобного не указано (чтобы было добавление символов)

все стандартное инициализация, получение ссылок, слушатель TextWatcher который выводит текст в TextView полученный из EditView

Comment: недостаточно данных. со стандартным виджетом без дополнительных настроек ничего подобного не происходит, с приложеным к вопросу коду тоже ничего подобного происходить не будет

Comment: Добавил данные. Результат: $1,111.11, а хотел 1,111.11

Comment: да, самому указать форматировать вывод как валюту текущей локали и потом спрашивать, почему так происходит :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в getCurrencyInstance() который возвращает объект форматирования чисел, денежных сумм или величин, представленных в процентах, для текущего или заданного регионального стандарта

а именно в

```
private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Переделав в простую строку, идет отображение без символов

Comment: Мы понимаем, что это ваш собственный вопрос, поэтому вам решение очевидно, но прямо говоря написанный текст является комментарием, а не полноценным ответом. Его надо либо расширить, либо преобразовать в комментарий, в расчёте, что кто-нибудь когда-нибудь даст более подробный и понятный пример.

Comment: вот как раз сейчас это нужно. проблема в чем - ясно. а что делать-то?

Comment: если double st = 14, а нужно вывести то string ts = Double.toString(st) и выводим ts в TextView.setText